# Android base64 decode crashes app

Tags: android, crash, base64, decoding

I'n using a base64 decode and for some reason it keeps crashing the app. I'm using this code somewhere else and it seems to work perfectly there. Maybe theres something wrong with the class im using it in??

Heres my class:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Users>
{
    public MyListAdapter()
    {
        super(SearchActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, myUsers);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
        View itemView = convertView;

        if(itemView == null)
        {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        //Find the user to work with
        Users currentUser = myUsers.get(position);

        //Fill the view
        TextView text;
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        text.setText(currentUser.getName());

        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_location);
        text.setText(currentUser.getLocation());

        if(!currentUser.getPicture().equals("noPicture"))
        {
            String temp = currentUser.getPicture();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_picture);
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(temp, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
        }

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Its crashing on the following line:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(temp, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Does anyone see a reason why it would crash?

Comment: Perhaps `temp` is not valid base64 data? Speculation aside, look at (and post) the logcat output at the time of the crash; you will normally find very helpful information there.

Comment: Is there a way of just showing the errors in the logcat?

Comment: You can filter what you view but it's really best to look at everything at the time of the failure... useful debugging details are often not printed as errors but rather just informative entries.